# Possible to reposition Adobe flash permission popup?

Tags: html, css, flash, adobe

[image]

Any one know if it is possible reposition Adobe flash permission popup?
Example to align left?

I am embedding a flash object from within a smaller Iframe and the permission dialogue is out of view

Suggestions appreciated

Comment: AFAIK there's no way you can manipulate that generic popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the Flash SWF is larger than the iframe it's inside and the iframe has scroll bars.

I would recommend resizing the swf to fit in the iframe, then check for camera access, which will trigger the settings pop-up, and then resize the swf back.

Comment: Yes you got it bang on... This sounds interesting how can I check if camera access is approved ?

Comment: @Webby, when you attach a camera to either a `NetStream` or to a `Video` Flash displays the privacy dialog.  When the user accepts, the `Camera` object dispatches a `status` event and the `code` will either be `Camera.Muted` (user clicked deny) or `Camera.Unmuted` (user clicked allow).

Comment: So can I check with JavaScript?

Comment: @Webby, no, with ActionScript inside the Flash app.